# How to draw a line on the diameter of a sphere in ThreeJs?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Suppose I've got a sphere like this:

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 1, 32, 32 );
window.sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( window.sphere );
```

How would I then draw a line around the diameter of a sphere? Preferably parallel to the x axis. The end goal here is to use such a line in conjunction with text to illustrate size (eg this sphere is 10m across).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this trick:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xaaaaaa } );
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 32, 32, 32 );
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( sphere );

var geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry( 31.9, 0.16, 64, 100 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } );
var torus = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
torus.rotation.x = Math.PI/2;
scene.add( torus );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/10hemttk/36/

**Upd.** well, this way is more correct:

```
var rad = 32,
    delta = 0.05,
    segs = 64,
    material = null,
    geometry = null,
    circle = null,
    sphere = null;

material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } ),
geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry( rad+delta, segs ),    
geometry.vertices.shift();
circle = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
circle.rotation.x = Math.PI/2;
scene.add( circle );

material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xaaaaaa } );
geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( rad, segs, segs );
sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( sphere );
```

Comment: You did not see the yellow line around the sphere? Strange. In any case, the trick is clear: to draw the torus major radius equal to or slightly less than the radius of the sphere with a second radius close to zero.

Comment: I don't see anything at all in the jsfiddle, it's a black screen. This seems very hacky, surely there must be a way to draw a line along the outside edge of a sphere?

Comment: Ah I see, you're using a circle to create a slice out of the sphere. Thanks!